# Looking to check for one's or zeros in a Bitstring

Tags: c#

Does anyone have an idea how to check for one's or zeros in a Bitstring? The below code checks for ones and zeros in a string, but I would like to add an extension bitstring that does the same thing. This way, I can use the method on the bitstring itself with out having to first evaluate the string.

Currently, I have to check before I entered the bitstring method.

```
            string MustBeBitsInStringOnesOrZeros = "11001";
        bool boTesting = Is1Or0(MustBeBitsInStringOnesOrZeros);
        // I would like to add an extension to check for ones and zeros
        // Example: MustBeBitsInStringOnesOrZeros.Is1Or0();
        if (boTesting == true)
        {
            Bitstring a = new Bitstring(MustBeBitsInStringOnesOrZeros);
        }
        else
        {
            string b = MustBeBitsInStringOnesOrZeros;
        }
    private static bool Is1Or0(string stringBit)
    {
        // This function check each
        // character in a string for "1"
        // or "0".
        bool results = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < stringBit.Length; i++)
        {
            var x = stringBit[i];
            if (x == '1' || x == '0')
            {
                results = true;
            }
            else
            {
                results = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
```

===
Modified to show results of Bassie's example from a sealed class.

Bassie,

Well, what I was trying to say was that I cannot place the method in the sealed class with the keyword 'this' in the method. So I created another class but, I have to use it a different way and I wanted to use it the way you call it.

```
//I have to use it this way:
Bitstring OnesAndZeroCheck = new Bitstring(); // Bitstring is in a sealed class
Boolean g = OnesAndZeroCheck.IsBitstring2("1100111100011100101010101010101101010101010"); // Is in the sealed class
//but want to call it this way:
var successInput = "1101";
successInput.Is1Or0(); // true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could define your extension method like this

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool Is1Or0(this string stringBit) 
        => stringBit.All(c => c == '1' || c == '0');
}
```

And call with

```
var successInput = "1101";
successInput.Is1Or0(); // true

var failureInput = "1121"
failureInput.Is1Or0(); // false
```

From [MSDN Enumerable.All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netcore-3.1):

> Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.

This works because a string is actually just an `IEnumerable` of `char` - so when we call the `IEnumerable.All()` extension method, we check the condition against each individual char in the string

Note you will need to include `using System.Linq;` to your file that contains the extension method

Comment: `code` public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool Is1Or0(this string stringBit) 
        =>             return stringBit.Trim().Replace("1", "").Replace("0", "").Length == 0;
}`code`

Comment: Got it... Thank you much for your help.

Comment: Thank you Bassie, However, I forgot to ask will this work in a public sealed class or how can it work in the public sealed class? Just like that (successInput.Is1Or0();). I noticed that I cannot use 'this' in the sealed class.

Comment: @DemarcPoint You should be able to call the method from a sealed class yes, or are you wondering if `StringExtensions` should be sealed?

Comment: Bassie, I modified my original post to reflect what I was trying to say. How I have to use the extension and call the method.

Comment: @DemarcPoint Please share the code for `BitString` class

Comment: The code came from a Sponge Constructions and SHA-3 Hashing project at Code Project; "https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1227359/Sponge-Constructions-and-SHA-Hashing-Functions-a" The (Project: SpongeConstructions.Core, Bitstring.cs). At about line 658 it is where I placed the code.

Answer (score 1):

tested in video.

https://youtu.be/CgMFYctc3Ak

```
public static bool isBitstring(string s)
{
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        if (!(c >= '0' && c <= '1')) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}


    string str = "100000011100101010010101";

    if (isBitstring(str))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("is Bitstring");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("is not Bitstring");
    }
```

Comment: just using, using System;

Comment: if you want, you can use short if statement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26118522)